# How to update an aggregate with nested lists using spring-boot-data-rest/jpa and kotlin?

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a `CrudRepository` to persist a `GameDay` using Spring Boot Data Rest. The POST method works, the update method also works when there is only one `Match`. But do not work if there is more than one `Match`. How should I configure JPA to work correctly?

Github: https://github.com/marciovmartins/spring-boot-data-rest-deep-aggregate-problem

GameDayRepository.kt

```kotlin
package com.github.marciovmartins.soccermanager.gameDay

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface GameDayRepository : CrudRepository<GameDay, Long>
```

GameDay.kt

```kotlin
package com.github.marciovmartins.soccermanager.gameDay

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
import java.time.LocalDate
import javax.persistence.CascadeType
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.EnumType
import javax.persistence.Enumerated
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn
import javax.persistence.OneToMany
import javax.validation.Constraint
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext
import javax.validation.Payload
import javax.validation.Valid
import javax.validation.constraints.Max
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty
import javax.validation.constraints.PastOrPresent
import javax.validation.constraints.PositiveOrZero
import javax.validation.constraints.Size
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

@Suppress("unused")
@Entity(name = "gameDays")
class GameDay(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @field:PastOrPresent
    var date: LocalDate,

    @field:Size(max = 255)
    var quote: String?,

    @field:Size(max = 50)
    var author: String?,

    @field:Size(max = 2048)
    var description: String?,

    @field:Valid
    @field:NotEmpty
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_day_id", nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    var matches: Set<Match>,
)

@Suppress("unused")
@Entity(name = "matches")
class Match(
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Column(name = "match_order")
    var order: Short? = null,

    @field:Valid
    @field:NotEmpty
    @field:BothTeams
    @JoinColumn(name = "match_id", nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    var matchPlayers: Set<MatchPlayer>
)

@Suppress("unused")
@Entity(name = "match_players")
class MatchPlayer(
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var team: Team,

    @field:NotBlank
    @field:Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    var nickname: String,

    @field:Max(9)
    @field:PositiveOrZero
    var goalsInFavor: Short,

    @field:Max(9)
    @field:PositiveOrZero
    var goalsAgainst: Short,

    @field:Max(9)
    @field:PositiveOrZero
    var yellowCards: Short,

    @field:Max(9)
    @field:PositiveOrZero
    var blueCards: Short,

    @field:Max(9)
    @field:PositiveOrZero
    var redCards: Short,
) {
    enum class Team {
        A, B
    }
}

@MustBeDocumented
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Constraint(validatedBy = [BothTeams.BothTeamsConstraintValidator::class])
annotation class BothTeams(
    val message: String = "must have at least one player for team A and one player for team B",
    val groups: Array<KClass<*>> = [],
    val payload: Array<KClass<Payload>> = []
) {
    class BothTeamsConstraintValidator : ConstraintValidator<BothTeams, Set<MatchPlayer>> {
        override fun isValid(value: Set<MatchPlayer>?, context: ConstraintValidatorContext?): Boolean =
            value == null || value.isEmpty() || hasMatchPlayersFromBothTeams(value)

        private fun hasMatchPlayersFromBothTeams(value: Set<MatchPlayer>) = value.map { it.team }.toSet().size > 1
    }
}
```

Assertion failed with the request/response at the bottom

```
2022-02-08 22:17:19.635 ERROR 62234 --- [o-auto-1-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.github.marciovmartins.soccermanager.gameDay.Match] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be empty', propertyPath=matchPlayers, rootBeanClass=class com.github.marciovmartins.soccermanager.gameDay.Match, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message}'}
]] with root cause

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.github.marciovmartins.soccermanager.gameDay.Match] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be empty', propertyPath=matchPlayers, rootBeanClass=class com.github.marciovmartins.soccermanager.gameDay.Match, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:853) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:826) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:543) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:518) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:833) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:820) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy126.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy126.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:633) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:98) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy131.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.CrudRepositoryInvoker.invokeSave(CrudRepositoryInvoker.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeSave(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:181) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.saveAndReturn(RepositoryEntityController.java:446) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.putItemResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:366) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2022-02-08 22:17:19.655 ERROR 62234 --- [Pool-1-worker-2] o.s.t.w.reactive.server.ExchangeResult   : Request details for assertion failure:

> PUT http://localhost:37951/gameDays/23586
> accept-encoding: [gzip]
> host: [localhost:37951]
> accept: [*/*]
> Content-Type: [application/json]
> User-Agent: [Spring 5 WebClient]
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [2]
> Content-Length: [593]

{"date":"2022-02-08","quote":null,"author":null,"description":null,"matches":[{"order":1,"matchPlayers":[{"team":"A","nickname":"Ajax","goalsInFavor":5,"goalsAgainst":1,"yellowCards":1,"blueCards":2,"redCards":1},{"team":"B","nickname":"Zatanna","goalsInFavor":2,"goalsAgainst":1,"yellowCards":0,"blueCards":2,"redCards":0}]},{"order":2,"matchPlayers":[{"team":"A","nickname":"Red Bat Skull","goalsInFavor":2,"goalsAgainst":0,"yellowCards":1,"blueCards":1,"redCards":1},{"team":"B","nickname":"The Pyro Strange","goalsInFavor":3,"goalsAgainst":1,"yellowCards":2,"blueCards":1,"redCards":1}]}]}

< 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR Internal Server Error
< Vary: [Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers]
< Content-Type: [application/json]
< Transfer-Encoding: [chunked]
< Date: [Tue, 08 Feb 2022 21:17:18 GMT]
< Connection: [close]

{"timestamp":"2022-02-08T21:17:19.641+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","path":"/gameDays/23586"}
```

pom.xml

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Environment

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 17.0.1, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.13.0-28-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: The error comes from the validation as `Match.matchPlayers`  is empty. Just add the data you need in that field.

Comment: It is not empty. At the end of the stacktrace error there is the payload used.

Comment: If you print out the actual object, does the set have any items?

Comment: I added a example on github: https://github.com/marciovmartins/spring-boot-data-rest-deep-aggregate-problem

Comment: The original object yes. But the copied object after this line no: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/DefaultMergeEventListener.java#L247